# additional text if argument in \footnote

Tags: biblatex, macros, citing, footnotes

I am trying to make a custom footnote, which should print footnotes as follows:

*cf. author (title), year, page*

So far I tried to achieve this by using

```
\newcommand{\customfootcite}[2]{\footnote{cf. \citeauthor{#1} (\citetitle{#1}), \citeyear{#1}}}
```

Now I want to put in the page as an optional argument and display the abbreviation p. as I can with:

```
\footcite[p.100]{Citationkey}
```

I thought I could use a default argument, so that I don't have to implement some if logic which seemed a little overwhelming (in latex) to me...

```
\newcommand{\addcustompage}[1]{p. {#1}}
\newcommand{\customfootcite}[2][displaynothing??]{\footnote{cf. \citeauthor{#1} (\citetitle{#1}), \citeyear{#1} \addcustompage{#2}}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authortitle,
]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{#1}
\newcommand{\addcustompage}[1]{p. {#1}}
\newcommand{\customfootcite}[2]{\footnote{cf. \citeauthor{#1} (\citetitle{#1}), \citeyear{#1} \addcustompage{#2}}}
\addbibresource{sample.bib} %Imports bibliography file
\begin{document}

This is a custom foot cite.\customfootcite{latexcompanion}

\end{document}
```

I appreciate any help!

Edit:
I accepted moewe's answer, since the approach with a `\newcommand` was a little short-sighted and would cause trouble as explained by him

Comment: Welcome. // Would be great if you could embed your code fragments in a short complete Latex code, one we can jsut copy and run.

Comment: Thank you :) Okay, my MWE runs in overleaf!

Comment: Sorry, I could have known that those sample files differ. Thanks for the effort, your solution is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: You should really consider accepting moewe’s answer for the reasons he states.

Comment: @shoj You did good when accepting moewe's answer instead of mine. I deleted mine. I don't know what I was thinking when writing it. I should have realized issues with biblatex. Must have been a mental blackout on my side. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `biblatex` it is generally speaking a bad idea to combine several `\...cite` commands into one `\newcommand` (or indeed `\NewDocumentCommand`): You have to manually take care of the pre- and postnote, multiple citations do not come out as expected and you may mess up citation tracking features.

It is much more idiomatic to define a command like your `\customfootcite` with `\DeclareCiteCommand`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authortitle]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{#1}

\DeclareDelimFormat[customfootcite]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}

\newbibmacro*{customcite}{%
  \DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{\mkbibparens{##1}}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\printnames{labelname}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:title}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \printdate}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\customfootcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\iffieldundef{prenote}
     {\bibstring{confer}%
      \setunit{\addspace}}
     {\usebibmacro{prenote}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{customcite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \customfootcite{companion}
ipsum \customfootcite[100]{companion}
ipsum \customfootcite[See][]{companion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: 1 Cf. Goossens, Mittelbach and Samarin (LaTeX Companion), 1994. 2 Cf. Goossens, Mittelbach and Samarin (LaTeX Companion), 1994, p. 100. 3 See Goossens, Mittelbach and Samarin (LaTeX Companion), 1994.]

Comment: I recently tried to change the numeration of footnotes with this solution: `\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}`
It doesn't work, I guess that's due to the "custom definition"? How can I solve this?

Comment: @shoj The code shown here changes nothing about how footnotes are numbered (the example also uses the `article` class, which does not have `\chapter`s). I suggest you ask a new question about this with a suitable example document and a short explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: FWIW In https://gist.github.com/moewew/3172ca1d1827307d1570e8667124f2ba I can get `\counterwithout` to work as I expected. (The footnotes in chapter 2 are 4, 5 and 6. They do not restart at 1.)

Comment: Okay, I just found out that I was using another package (footmisc) which was supressing the wanted effect. I am sorry to cause you any more effort to check this. Most of the problems I have are basically due to using too many functions from different templates as a beginner. MWE is always key to find out what to do next, thats what I learned now!